# Java KeyStore KeyPair Retrieval Concerns Using Java and Javax Libraries

Tags: java, rsa, keystore

I am currently working on retrieving a KeyPair from my .jks using the Java and Javax built-in libraries rather than KeyTool or some API like BouncyCastle. The problem I am having is regarding the equality of my two KeyPair instances.
[image]

In the debugger screenshot above (where it is underlined) you can notice that the memory address of the KeyPair instances. The screenshot highlights that the memory addresses are not identical for **userKeys/privateKey** comparied with **keyPairFromKeyStore/privateKey** and consequently **userKeys** compared to **keyPairFromKeyStore**. However in the console screenshot below, the outputs reflect two distinct equality comparisons:

```
userKeys.getPrivate().equals(keyPairFromKeyStore.getPrivate()); // true
userKeys.getPublic().equals(keyPairFromKeyStore.getPublic()); // true
```

and it has returned true for both comparisons convincing me that the KeyPair contents are identical for both the public and private key comparisons. (Console screenshot below)
[image]

In the final line of the console screenshot, I had evaluated another equality comparison comparing:

```
keyPairFromKeyStore.equals(userKeys) // false
```

to which it output false.

For context, when I added my KeyPair to the .jks file using seyKeyEntry, I had used a X509Certificate chain containing two X509Certificate instances signed with "SHA256WithRSA" (one for my client-side KeyPair (dn = "CN=ROOT", in the 0th index of the certificate chain), and user-specific KeyPair (the pair stored to the .jks, "dn = "CN=TOP" & in the 1st index of the certificate chain).

My question is what are possible resaons for the last equality statement returning false?
If any more relevant infomration is needed, feel free to ask. I apologize in advance since I cannot post the actual code I wrote for academic reasons.

Comment: See the Javadoc. [`KeyPair`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html) does not override `Object.equals()`.

Comment: Yes! I was just looking into that I'm glad I got the assurance from someone else. Going to need to likely override the hashCode(...) method as well

Comment: You don't need any assurance from anybody else. Just what it says in the Javadoc. I don't know how you plan to override any methods in a `final` class.

Comment: I would not use `equals()` on any crypto object because equals is implementation dependent but Java may have access to multiple crypto providers using different implementations. Therefore I would strongly recommend only to compare the output of `getEncoded()` of public/private keys. getEncoded returns the crypto object in a standardized way.